# LogoutRequest has no PostLogoutRedirectUri in it when using React.js app with ... library

Tags: reactjs, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server 4 instance running at **https://localhost:5443/** and a client React.js application running at **http://localhost:3000/** and making a reference to the [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library in order to establish the communication. I've been following more or less [this](https://github.com/tappyy/react-IS4-auth-demo) article.

The way I've configured the client (in-memory) on the Identity Server is as follows:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "react-js-implicit-flow",
                    ClientName = "Some App name",
                    ClientUri = "http://localhost:3000",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                    RequireClientSecret = false,

                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc", },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signout-oidc" },

                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:3000" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "weatherapi.read"
                    },

                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
                }
```

and the way it looks like on the Ract.js app is like this:
[image]

In general, everything goes well. I can login and logout from the Identity Server but the issue is that here:

[image]

I get no value (it is null) and this stops the Identity server from redirecting me back to the client application right after logout. If I hard code it (http://localhost:3000/signout-oidc) it works. But for some reason it is just not available.

During the logout this is what the Identity Server logs show:

[image]

So, no error, no nothing but I still can not navigate back to the client app after logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide an idTokenHint (id token) with your logout request like the following:

```js
const mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings); 
const signoutUrl = await mgr.createSignoutRequest({id_token_hint: user.id_token});
window.location.href = signOutUrl.url;

//or
await mgr.signoutRedirect({id_token_hint: user.id_token});

//or just
await mgr.signoutRedirect();
//it will try to attach id_token internally
```

Lack of the token is the reason for Identityserver to skip the post_logout_redirect_url parameter.

Identityserver has to validate the parameter against the client's configuration, but without the token it can't.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: added a piece of code

Comment: I did that, so the sign out url looks like that: https://localhost:5443/connect/endsession?id_token_hint={my_id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri={my_redirect_uri} but when it goes on the Identity Server - PostLogoutRedirectUri is not mapped. It is still null.

Comment: could you check the logs now again to find any information regarding token validation?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just made some small modifications. You can see it in my answer to this post.

Comment: updated the answer one more time :) according to the [source code](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/a8a70ce68bd07373abd7d33e016a97adc5d204bc/src/UserManager.js#L506) it must attach the parameter internally (but only in case you haven't cleared it before with removeUser())

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for (me thanks to answer by **@d_f**) was to change something on the client side and more specifically: src/services/userService/signoutRedirect.

[image]